# How can I pass a variable from an HTML script file to a javascript function in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I would like to get the users ip, and then load it onto the properties service. But, the html file script uses `javascript`, not google apps script, so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(String(userip), "1")
</script>
```

doesn't work. How can I make it work? Would be appreciated. 
Edit: context below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <base target="_top">

  </head>
  <body>
    `_insert webpage here_`
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(String(userip), "1")
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you want to retrieve the IP address of the user who accessed? Where will you put ``<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>``? If you provide the situation of when user's ip address is retrieved, more users may be able to think of the solution of your problem.

Comment: Edited the question to include the context

Comment: You will find details on how to pass the data back to the server side in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...)). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your backend language, you *can* insert the value dynamically - if, say, it's PHP, you could do `<%= $userIP %>` in the middle of that inline JS code.

However, best practices would dictate that a) your JS code all lives in a .js file, and b) there's only three ways to properly get data from the server to the client:

1. AJAX request from JS.
2. HTML `data-*` attributes on some arbitrary element(s), read them in JS.
3. `<script type="application/json"></script>`, read and parse it from JS, however this option requires special escaping of  in the json body

Comment: Ah maybe I wasn't clear enough. I'm using google apps script, which is why I tagged it with google-apps-script. Right now I'm thinking of passing the variable userid from this to my code.js file, but I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: ah, in that case i'm not sure :-/